# Difference between "I get" and "I am"

Tags: difference, passive-voice

Is there any differences between these sentences:

> 1. I get contacted by clients all the time
> 2. I am contacted by clients all the time

I heard people using both before. For me, I always use 2. If both are wrong, how do I change the sentence?

Comment: People say both of those. Number 2 sounds a bit more professional, perhaps? But there really isn't much difference, and no one is going to think you odd if you say the first one.

Comment: @MarielS: I suggest the opposite! As a general principle, using ***get*** as an "auxiliary" verb like this tends to be slangy / colloquial (I made [much the same point](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266372/come-over-here-get-over-here#comment497682_266372) yesterday).

Comment: In other words, you sound like a native speaker. The _get_ passive is perfectly normal.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica yes, "get" sounds more slangy. hence why I said that using "am" sounds a bit more professional. but both are commonly used by native speakers and should be fine in conversation.

Comment: @MarielS: My mistake. Dunno how I misread your first comment - somehow I thought you were saying "get" was "more professional". I agree with you completely, including the second comment (and John's point about "sound like a native speaker", since in practice we're not usually trying to sound more professional anyway).

Comment: As a student in Australia I was taught to avoid the word "get" as an Americanism, so I would use "am".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how formal you want to be.

In American speech  and informal writing a form of “get” followed by a passive participle is completely acceptable and means the same thing as a form of “be” followed by a passive participle.

In formal writing, the “be” form is used almost exclusively.

In short, you can use either informally in the U.S.